# Json.stringify TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Here is the Marker reference

```
var markers = [];
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: e.latLng, map: map });  
markers.push(marker); // add marker to the global array
```

My loop to markers...

```
    var jsonObj = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    {
        jsonObj.push({ latitude: markers[i].position, map: markers[i].map }); //key
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj)); // error
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each `marker` has a reference to the `map` instance, and the `map` instance, has an array of `markers` (Which, redundantly, each one of them has a reference to `map`).

Comment: I did not realized that I have the same key and that can be changed so instead of  `map: markers[i].map` I can have something like `mapKey: markers[i].map`  ?

Comment: I would not add the map instance at all. If you plan to have more than one map, I would create a key/value pair object with all map instances indexed by an id, and in your jsonObj instead of the whole map instace, store the id to retreive it later.